# substituting expressions

Tags: satisfiability, boolean-algebra

I have a set of expressions $E_1 .. E_n$ over boolean variables and I'm looking for an assignment to the variables so that all expressions are satisfied. Normally this would be NP-complete, but I found two particular properties over the set and I'm looking to combine and exploit them.

The idea I have is based on gaussian matrix elimination. In matrix elimination, you take a nonzero column and a row and use them to sweep the column from all other rows. Even for an integer matrix solution, you can find a solution in such a way if the number of rows is about the same as the number of columns and the matrix has exactly 1 solution. In my particular application, I have about as many variables as expressions and in some cases there is only 1 solution and the expressions do not imply each other. (property 1).

I take $E_1$ and one of it's variables. I combine $E_1$ with $E_2$ only if $E_2$ contains that variable. If so, I eliminate the variable from $E_2$ and I will (deterministically but somewhat arbitrarily) eliminate some more variables from $E_2$ that are both in $E_1$ and $E_2$. I keep the expressions as a truth table. Suppose for example that I want to eliminate a, b and c, $E_2$ would become

```
E_2 = 
    (substitute/a,b,c/0,0,0 (E_1 && E_2)) ||
    (substitute/a,b,c/0,0,1 (E_1 && E_2)) ||
    (substitute/a,b,c/0,1,0 (E_1 && E_2)) ||
    ...
    (substitute/a,b,c/1,1,1 (E_1 && E_2))
```

$E_2$ may take over some new variables from $E_1$. I would then combine $E_1$ and $E_3$ in the same way until $E_1$ with $E_n$ and then I'd start with $E_2$ with $E_3$ .. $E_n$ etc. at the end, $E_n$ will be an expression in a single variable. Normally this can lead to an exponential blowup for the size of an expression, but in my particular application, I found that because of variables are eliminated, $E_i$ && $E_k$ never has more than 39 variables (Property 2). Truth tables in 39 variables are still feasible.

Unfortunately, unlike matrix gaussian sweep, when substituting the variables, I lose information. For example, if
$E_1 = a \rightarrow b$ and $E_2 = b \rightarrow c$ and I'm sweeping with $E_1:b$. $E_2$ would become $E_2 = a \rightarrow c$.
Before the sweep, $a,b,c = 0,1,0$ was not a valid assignment, while after the sweep it is valid.

I'm not sure if this limitation can be overcome. Perhaps I should remember the original $E_2 = b \rightarrow c$ in a side-set of expressions, but then how to combine all the expressions in the side set? Or can I perhaps add $c$ to $E_1$, but then Property 2 won't hold anymore? Is there some 3rd property I should look for in my set of expressions, so that this method would work?

Truth table example

The truth table for $E_1 = a \rightarrow b$ (used above) is:

```
E_1 =
-------------
|a|b|allowed|
-------------
|0|0|    1  |
|0|1|    1  |
|1|0|    0  |
|1|1|    1  |
-------------
```

A truth table can express any boolean expression (or function) and the size is exponential in the number of variables.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing, or what problem you're solving.  What kinds of expressions can each $E_i$ take?  Are those arbitrary boolean formulas (with an arbitrary number of variables and any number of disjunctions, conjunctions, and negations, possibly nested)?  I don't understand how you are combining $E_1$ with $E_2$.  What does it mean to "eliminate" a variable from an expression?  Can you be more precise, and maybe also give a few simple examples to illustrate your ideas?  Are you familiar with resolution? Have you tried using a SAT solver?

Comment: Is my example in the gray block where I combine $E_1$ and $E_2$ while eliminating three variables unclear? Initially, $E_i$ are all truth tables with 4 variables max. They cannot be arbitrary formula's, but let's assume for now. When sweeping in the mentioned way, it appears that any $E_i$ && $E_k$ will have a limited number of variables (this limit is now reduced to  23). It follows also that $E_i$ will never have more than 23 variables if applied this way. SAT-solvers cannot solve this as it would crack SHA-2.

Comment: I don't understand what an expression is, or what it means to say that an expression $E_i$ is a truth table.  (Separately: If solving your problem is at least as hard as cracking SHA-2, solving your problem is probably infeasible.)

Comment: I expected you would know, but I added an example. There's also a lot on the internet about turning expressions into truth tables.

Comment: OK, so an expression is just a logical formula (with any number of variables and any number of disjunctions, conjunctions, and/or negations, possibly nested).  So what exactly do you mean by "combining" two expressions?  There are many ways one could possibly combine two expressions.  What exactly do you mean by "eliminating" a variable from an expression?  What do you mean by a "sweep"?  Can you edit your question to define your terms?  It seems you have some procedure in mind, but I can't decipher what it is.